# How can I integrate Stripe without using JS? I have a problem with creating a session to stripe?

Tags: php, paypal, stripe-payments

Since I have payments, through PayPal I try to integrate payments through Stripe. My system works on the following principle:

- dashboard.php - here I have , in which Gateway is selected (paypal or stripe) and the corresponding amount that the client wants to add to his personal balance

  ````
        ```
        <form action="/balance" method="post" id="form-balance" data-ajax="true">
        stripe: <input type="radio" name="method" value="stripe" id="method_stripe">
        paypal: <input type="radio" name="method" value="paypal" id="method_paypal">
        </div>
        <div class="form" style="width:330px">
            <label class="required">Amount:</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="number" name="price" value="" min="1" autofocus required>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">continue</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
        ```
  ````
- balance.php - (ajax) this is the ajax part. In it I check and process the sent data: gateway, amount.

  ```
  <?php
  $stop = $res = [];
  switch ( $subaction ) {
      case 'balance':
          $sum = ( isset($_REQUEST['amount']) && validate_price($_REQUEST['amount']) ) ? round($_REQUEST['amount'], 2) : 35;
          $method = ( isset($_REQUEST['method']) && trim($_REQUEST['method']) != '' ) ? strip_tags( trim($_REQUEST['method']) ) : '';

      if ( ! $sum ) {
          $stop[] = $lng->data['Enter the amount to be filled'];
      } elseif ( $sum < $config['minimal_transfer'] ) {
          $stop[] = $lng->data['Minimum amount to power the deposit']." - <b>".$config['valuta']['EUR']."".$config['minimal_transfer'].".</b>";
      }

      if ( $stop ) {
          $res['answer'] = 'stop';
          $res['error'] = $stop;
      } else {
          $db->query( "INSERT INTO " . PREFIX_S . "_payment (`user_id`, `sum`, `temp`, `date`) VALUES ('" . USER_ID . "', '{$sum}', '1', '{$_DATE}')" );
          $id = $db->insert_id();

          $res['answer'] = 'ok';

          switch ( $method ) {
              // stripe
              case 'stripe':
                  $params = [
                      'PAYMENT_AMOUNT' => $sum,
                      'PAYMENT_DESC_BASE64' => base64_encode($lng->data['Funding of an account'].' #' . SITE_ID),
                      'PAYMENT_NO' => $id
                  ];
                  $location = "/site/payment_do/stripe_charget?" . http_build_query($params);

                  $res['eval'] = "window.location.href = '{$location}';";
              break;

              // paypal
              case 'paypal':
                  $params = [
                      'PAYMENT_AMOUNT' => $sum,
                      'PAYMENT_DESC_BASE64' => base64_encode($lng->data['Funding of an account'].' #' . SITE_ID),
                      'PAYMENT_NO' => $id
                  ];
                  $location = "/site/payment_do/paypal_charget?" . http_build_query($params);

                  $res['eval'] = "window.location.href = '{$location}';";
                  break;
              default:
                  $params = [
                      'PAYMENT_AMOUNT' => $sum,
                      'PAYMENT_NO' => $id
                  ];
                  $_SESSION['params'] = $params;
                  break;
          }

      }
      break;

  default: die( 'error' );

  }
  $content = json_encode($res);
  header( "Content-type: application/json; charset=" . $config['charset'] );
  echo $content;
  ```
- payment.php - If everything is fine in balance.php (ajax) I send the data to the appropriate gateway for payment to payment.php. It sends to the appropriate official gateway (paypal.com or stripe.com) for payment

  ```
  <?php

  $_TIME = time();
  $_DATE = date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", $_TIME );

  require ENGINE_DIR . '/autoloader.php';

  /*Array
  (
      [PAYMENT_AMOUNT] => 35
      [PAYMENT_DESC_BASE64] => 0JfQsNGF0YDQsNC90LLQsNC90LUg0L3QsCDRgdC80LXRgtC60LAgIzI1
      [PAYMENT_NO] => 2578
      [PAYEE_PURSE] => 
      [init] => site
      [do] => payment_do
      [action] => stripe_charget
      [lang] => 7
  )
  */

  define('STRIPE_SUCCESS_URL', '/site/payment_do/success/'); 
  define('STRIPE_CANCEL_URL', 'site/payment_do/cancel/'); 
  $productName = "Funding an Account";  
  $productID = "DP12345";  
  $currency = "eur"; 
  $params = ( isset($_REQUEST['params']) && is_array($_REQUEST['params']) ) ? $_REQUEST['params'] : [];
  $productPrice = ( isset($_REQUEST['PAYMENT_AMOUNT']) && $_REQUEST['PAYMENT_AMOUNT'] > 10 ) ? $_REQUEST['PAYMENT_AMOUNT'] : 35;
  $stripeAmount = round($productPrice*100, 2);  // Convert product price to cent 

  $res = $stop = [];
  ini_set("display_errors", "1"); error_reporting(E_ALL);

  switch ( $action ) {
      case 'stripe_charget':
          // Include Stripe PHP library  
          require_once ENGINE_DIR . '/stripe-php/init.php';       
          // Set API key 
                  \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($config['stripe']['stripe_api_key']); 

                  $response = array( 
                      'status' => 0, 
                      'error' => array( 
                          'message' => 'Invalid Request!'    
                      ) 
                  ); 

                  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { 
                      $input = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
                      $request = json_decode($input);
                      //print_r($request);
                      //die;
                  } 

                  if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) { 
                      http_response_code(400); 
                      echo json_encode($response); 
                      exit; 
                  }
                  if(!empty($request->checkoutSession)){ 
                      // Create new Checkout Session for the order 
                      try { 
                          $session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([ 
                              'payment_method_types' => ['card'], 
                              'line_items' => [[ 
                                  'price_data' => [ 
                                      'product_data' => [ 
                                          'name' => $productName, 
                                          'metadata' => [ 
                                              'pro_id' => $productID 
                                          ] 
                                      ], 
                                      'unit_amount' => $stripeAmount, 
                                      'currency' => $currency, 
                                  ], 
                                  'quantity' => 1, 
                                  'description' => $productName, 
                              ]], 
                              'mode' => 'payment', 
                              'success_url' => STRIPE_SUCCESS_URL.'?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}', 
                              'cancel_url' => STRIPE_CANCEL_URL, 
                          ]); 
                      }catch(Exception $e) {  
                          $api_error = $e->getMessage();  
                      } 

                      if(empty($api_error) && $session){ 
                          $response = array( 
                              'status' => 1, 
                              'message' => 'Checkout Session created successfully!', 
                              'sessionId' => $session['id'] 
                          ); 
                      }else{ 
                          $response = array( 
                              'status' => 0, 
                              'error' => array( 
                                  'message' => 'Checkout Session creation failed! '.$api_error    
                              ) 
                          ); 
                      } 
                  } 
                  unset($_SESSION['params']);
                  // Return response 
                  echo json_encode($response);
      break;


      case 'paypal':
          $id = ( isset($_REQUEST['params']['account']) && (int)$_REQUEST['params']['account'] > 0 ) ? (int)$_REQUEST['params']['account'] : 0;
          break;

      default:
          die( 'error action' );
  }
  ```

When I use stripe js, I get the following error because I can't send the data to balance.php and from there to payment.php

> {"status":0,"error":{"message":"Invalid Request!"}}

If I do the code as described here: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/integration-builder, it works but this way I stop working for payments via PayPal - I want to have two working payment systems in this case, i don't have to use js on stripe.

[image]

Comment: To accept both PayPal and Debit/Credit Card payments in the most simple way, you may wish to consider this solution: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client ; there is a server pattern version of the same that can be paired with 'Create Order' and 'Capture Order' on the backend: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/

Comment: It's not possible to make payments with Stripe Checkout without JS. You still need to call the `redirectToCheckout` method to complete the payment: https://stripe.com/docs/js/checkout/redirect_to_checkout